# Syntax error in SQL stored procedure to send emails?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, email, stored-procedures

Hi I have written a stored procedure to retrieve information about server disk drives that are running low on space. Now I am just trying to write another stored procedure to send out email notifications to notify clients the server disk space is low. Here is what I have:

```
--Creating alert notification
CREATE PROC dbo.sp_drivespacelow1_alerts
        @from varchar(100),
        @to varchar(200),
        @subject varchar(100),
        @threshold int  -- number of MB under which to launch an alert
AS

        SET NOCOUNT ON

        DECLARE @list nvarchar(2000) = '';

        WITH core AS ( 
                SELECT DISTINCT
                        s.volume_mount_point [Drive],
                        CAST(s.available_bytes / 1048576 as decimal(12,2))      [AvailableMBs]
                FROM 
                    sys.master_files f
                       CROSS APPLY sys.dm_os_volume_stats(f.database_id, f.[file_id]) s
    )

        SELECT @list = @list + ' ' + Drive + ', '
        FROM core
        WHERE AvailableMBs < @threshold

        IF LEN(@list) > 3 BEGIN
                DECLARE @msg varchar(500) = 'Low Disk Space Notification. The following     drives are currently reporting less than ' 
                + CAST(@threshold as varchar(12)) + ' MB free: ' + @list

                EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = 'xxxxx',
                @recipients = @to,
                @subject = @subject,
                @body = @msg

        END

        RETURN 0
GO --Check done every 5 mins

--To Run:
EXEC master.dbo.sp_drivespace_alerts
      @threshold = 5120 --5 GB
      @from = 'sqlalert@noreply.com'
      @subject = 'Low diskspace alert -ServerName Here'
      @to = 'marakelly84@yahoo.ie'
```

Here is what I'm using to check the disk space:

```
--Returns informations on drives with less than 5 GBs of disk space
CREATE TABLE #drives (
        drive char,
        [free] int
)

INSERT INTO #drives
EXEC master..xp_fixeddrives

SELECT drive, [free] 
FROM #drives 
WHERE [free] < 5 * 102 

drop table #drives --must get rid of temporary tables in order to run again
```

Right now the stored procedure to check the disk space is fine, but the one to send out the email notifications keeps giving me back this error:
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 3, Procedure sp_drivespacelow_alerts, Line 37
There is already an object named 'sp_drivespacelow_alerts' in the database.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near '@from','@subject'

And if I comment out those two bits of code and run this error:
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near '@to'.

Please help thank you!

Comment: Re-tagged with `sql-server` as `mysql` is obvisously not being used

Answer (score -1):

If you are running this:

```
--To Run:
EXEC master.dbo.sp_drivespace_alerts
      @threshold = 5120 --5 GB
      @from = 'sqlalert@noreply.com'
      @subject = 'Low diskspace alert -ServerName Here'
      @to = 'marakelly84@yahoo.ie'
```

I think you want to do it this way:

```
--To Run:
CALL master.dbo.sp_drivespace_alerts (
      5120, --5 GB
      'sqlalert@noreply.com',
      'Low diskspace alert -ServerName Here',
      'marakelly84@yahoo.ie');
```

Comment: Hi thank you I tried your suggestion but am now getting this error: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near 'master'.

Comment: My mistake.  I had the parenthesis in the wrong place.  Try now.

Comment: The original `exec` is nearly correct. Just missing commas. It shouldn't have parentheses or `call` in SQL Server (call is only understood in an ODBC escape sequence)